# cassandra python driver bind to int

Tags: python, cassandra, prepared-statement

I am using the datastax driver for python. It seems the preparedstatement can not bind to an int input?

```
item_by_user1 = session.execute(item_by_user_lookup_stmt.bind(int(123)))
```

it dumps the error message
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Is python driver restricted to work with text fields only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind a tuple containing an Int, not just an int. The `has no len()` error is caused by the driver trying to count how many elements are in bind parameter. Since the bind parameter is is an int it can't call len() and throws an error.

```
item_by_user1 = session.execute(item_by_user_lookup_stmt.bind((int(123),)))
                                                              ^         ^
```

Why do we need the , because of tuple syntax in python,
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax